# Add paragraph styling only in certain sections

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I am writing my Masters thesis in LaTeX. I'm using the university template which is quite complex so I haven't tweaked it much as I'm new to LaTeX. My problem is that the paragraph style here seems to be the default one for latex that uses indentations without any vertical spacing between the paragraphs. I like my paragraphs to not have indents but be separated with some spaces between them. So, I inserted the following in the preamble.

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1in}
```

It worked alright but I ran into an unexpected problem. It kind of screwed my Abstract pages, TOC etc which are defined in the sty file that I don't want to mess around with. So, I would like for this style to occur only from my Introduction "section" and beyond not in the frontmatter. How can I have only the sections and subsections etc have this style without touching that on the other parts like abstract page, preface, TOC, reference etc.

Comment: I have never tried it myself, but does using the [`parskip` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) instead of your `\setlength`s help? (see also [“Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-ra).)

Comment: If the university has provided a style for you to use, is it really a good idea to go changing that? Also note that the majority of printed books you own probably use the "no skip and indent" style. There's a reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sfactor - I don't know your thesis style, of course, but in most the following will work:

```
\documentclass{yourthesisclass}
\author{moi}
\title{Epigraphy Upon Stalagmites In Pre-Historic Europe}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1in}
\include{thewholethesis}
\end{document}
```

So, the basic idea is to reset them after the frontmatter. You can do it in the text, no problem.

BTW, you can also go:

```
\parindent0pt
\parskip0.1in
```

in the same place.....

Comment: It can be good to add some stretchability in `\parskip` so that `\flushbottom` has some chance of succeeding. E.g., `\setlength\parskip{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}` or whatever,

Comment: @Will: +1, only that `12pt` is usually just too much.