# Paragraph spacer: blank line and no indent, instead of indent

Tags: spacing, indentation, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r)

I would like to have my paragraphs separated by a blank line, with no indentation of the first line on the new paragraph, instead of the standard newline with indentation.

This gives me the desired results:

```
...and this is how the first paragraph ends.\
\noindent After a blank line, I'm ready to begin a new part of this story...
```

However, it's quite tedious to have to write `\\ (newline) (newline) \noindent` at every paragraph break. How do I tell LaTeX that this is what I want by specifying this *once*?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A straightforward way would be:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
```

However, you could consider to use the [parskip](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package. It works better with lists, for example.

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
```

It uses `0.5\baselineskip`, but you can change that. The option `parfill` is a useful addition: it avoids that a paragraph ends almost flush right. So, paragraphs could easier be distinguished. This is done by modifying the `\parfillskip` length (`\setlength{\parfillskip}{30\p@ \@plus 1fil}`).

Comment: For the KOMA-Script classes, there's also the option `[parskip]`, like e.g. `\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook}`.