# No paragraph indentation everywhere, except for specific paragraphs

Tags: indentation

By default, I prefer to have no paragraph indentation (which I have implemented by putting `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` in the preamble of my document), but for my current document I would like to be able to return to the standard paragraph indentation (i.e. what I would get if I hadn't put that command in my preamble) for certain paragraphs. I tried putting `\indent` in front of the paragraphs I wanted to affect, but it didn't work (presumably because the command `\indent` uses the value of `\parindent`). The only way I can think of to do what I want would be to leave the default `\parindent` alone, and put `\noindent` almost everywhere, but that would be kind of a pain. Is there any better way to do this?

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-ra/57#57) seems to imply that it might be necessary to write my own document class in order to accomplish this. Is that really true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don’t you renew the definition of `\indent`?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{1\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\indent}{\hspace*{10.95003pt}\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\verb+\parindent+ = \the\parindent

These are some paragraphs

\indent and this is on is not indendet

as you can see here \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. May I ask, is 1em the length of a default indent (since I want the indents to be exactly as they would have been without setting `\parindent` to 0)? If so, how/where did you find that out? I might want to do this process with other settings in the future.

Comment: @Zev you could use `\showthe\parindent` to print the length into the LOG file or `\the\parindetn` to type it in the Text. While testing I noticed, that the length seems to be changed at the `\begin{document}` so put the command after that. (I added it to the example.)