# How do I turn off default paragraph indentation?

Tags: indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No paragraph indentation everywhere, except for specific paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18788/no-paragraph-indentation-everywhere-except-for-specific-paragraphs)

I'm writing a LaTeX article, and by default paragraphs are being indented.  I'd like to opt-in to indentation by typing `\indent` before each paragraph, instead of needing to opt-out with `\noindent`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18788/3240

Comment: As @Thorsten noted, you would have to change `\parindent` and redefine `\indent`. Default for `\parindent` is `20pt`.