# Paragraph spacing affecting table of contents

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, parskip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r)

I am trying to increase the spacing between paragraphs, using

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
```

and it seems to work fine -- except it also increases the spacing of lines in the table of contents etc.

I tried the following as a workaround:

```
\begin{spacing}{1}
\listoftodos % Remove this for the final document
     \tableofcontents
     \listoffigures 
     \listoftables
     \printnomenclature
 \end{spacing}
```

but that didn't fix the problem.

My question is: Is there any way I can increase the spacing between paragraphs **only** for the actual body of the document and not anywhere else (TOC, etc.)

Comment: @Seamus: Thanks for the reply, but this is more of a paragraph spacing issue rather than a line spacing one, so unless I am not seeing the obvious I don't think my question is a duplicate.

Comment: I should've checked first ... possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r. Also, [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) :) And a side note: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: @Hamza Ah yes. sorry. See doncherry's comment. I flagged this as a duplicate of the wrong question. I don't know how that happened...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `\usepackage{parskip}`. This package also removes the indentation at the beginning of paragraphs, which usually is desired when you're adding space between the paragraphs. If I recall correctly, this package is superior to tampering with `\parskip` because it leaves footnote spacing unaltered, but don't pin me down on this one.

The package `setspace`, which provides the `spacing` environment, is for line-spacing, i.e. space between two successive lines of text *within the same paragraph*.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 9):

Either use package [parskip](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

that supports smart switching to paragraph separation instead of paragraph indent for classes, that does not support this itself, or switch to a class, that supports it:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you don't like both suggestions, you may use a toc package like [tocstyle](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocstyle):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

or reset `\parskip` at start of the toc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I've delayed the `\addtocontents` because the `.aux` file has to be opened for writing before you can write to it.