# how to not indent all paragraphs in the document

Tags: indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r)

I would not indent all paragraph of my document. instead putting `\noindent` at the beginning of the paragraph how can i do in a easy and fast way? there is maybe a package that helps me to do that?

Comment: Do you want a bit of space in between the paragraphs instead? Then have a look at [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42)

Comment: well not exactly...Instead to use \noindent every time I would a way to do this for entire document

Comment: \setlength\parindent{0pt}

Comment: Putting `\parindent=0pt` in the preamble.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you load the [parskip](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/parskip) package. It sets (i) `\parindent` to 0 and (ii) `\parskip` -- the extra whitespace between paragraphs -- to a non-zero ("glue" or strechable) length. If you have no indentation at the start of paragraphs, it's generally considered a must to increase the separation between paragraphs. Otherwise, readers may be quite unsure at times where a paragraph break occurs. In addition, the package also adjusts the vertical spacing between items of a list environment.

Comment: If this is the answer, the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @doncherry -- you're right. I failed to follow the link in your comment before providing this answer. Sorry.