# Have new line between paragraphs, no indentation

Tags: spacing, indentation, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r)

I am sure that this must be a dup, but I can't find the right keywords to search for.  So I am posting.

Right now my latex paragraphs look like this:

```
The paragraph does not start out with
an indent.  But when you make a new 
paragraph there is an indent.  
     This is a new paragraph.  Can 
you see the indent?  
     This is another paragraph.
```

I would like to have no indenting but and an empty line between paragraphs.
This is what I am using to remove the indents:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0}
```

But I am not sure how to add in new lines.  I think it is something like this:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1}
```

Happy Canada Day!

Comment: I asked the very same question! See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195908/latex-multiple-linebreaks

Comment: @rlb.usa: I've voted to close this qn as a duplicate, although I'm not sure that the answers here aren't better than there.  Any firm views on the matter?

Comment: Whichever solution you choose, if you use a `minipage` environment be sure to check this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110605/paragraph-spacing-within-a-tikz-environment

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Just include the following before \begin{document}

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
```

Comment: +1 for this, much better to include a package than to fiddle round with parskip or noindent.

Comment: Before I put this in the preamble, I had been using this code to create a heading: `\null\hfill\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}}
  Name \\
  \today
\end{tabular}` Now it is no longer flushed right, but set to the left of the right margin a bit. How can I fix this?

Comment: What does "parfill" do ? I can't see the difference.

Comment: Note that when using the `amsthm` package to include theorems or definitions in your document, the above solution removes the blank line before a theorem.

Comment: @Abby What is the fix for that?

Comment: @CalebStanford: 
\parfillskip is inserted at the end of a paragraph. By this option, i.e. by raising this value, you avoid that a paragraph ends almost flush right. So, paragraphs could easier be distinguished. according to https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11283

Answer (score 53):

Use the `\noindent` command.

Example:

```
This is my paragraph.

\noindent My second paragraph
```

Check the following out for more detail: [LaTeX:Layout guide](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Layout)

Comment: Note that `\noindent` is only for occasional special effects.  The correct way to do this is by using the `\parindent` and `\parskip` parameters mentioned elsewhere in this thread and in the duplicate answer.

Answer (score 15):

Single line

```
\parskip = \baselineskip
```

Two lines

```
\parskip = \baselineskip
\multiply \parskip by 2
```

or

```
\parskip = 2\baselineskip % no shrink and no stretch
```

Fixed vertical space

```
\parskip = 1cm % Or 1 mm or 1in, for example
```

Stretchable and shrinkable space

```
\parskip = 12pt plus 6pt minus 4pt
```

Zero space

```
\parskip = 0pt
```

Comment: This still leaves me with an indentation after an extra line. How could I remove that indent?

Answer (score 4):

One solution if it's only locally you want this is to add `\newline` at the end of a paragraph to get the empty line between the paragraphs and `\noindent` at the beginning of the next i.e.

> The first paragraph start out without an
>   indent. \newline
>
> \noindent This is a new paragraph
>   without indent.

However, if you want the new lines between the paragraphs throughout the document this solution is tedious...