# Paragraph Spacing within a Tikz Environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, paragraphs, minipage

I am looking to replicate the look of paragraphs within a tikz environment (actually a minipage).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,backgrounds,arrows}   
\usepackage{tabularx}
\tikzset{mybox/.style= {draw=black,fill=black!5,thick,rectangle,rounded corners,inner xsep=40pt, inner ysep=14pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\node [mybox] (box) { \begin{minipage}[t!]{0.75\textwidth}
{Then we look for \textbf{clues}. 

Okay, this is a good time to find any direction words. Those are words that tell you how the two blanks are related.

Here's one: ``while.'' The word ``while'' sets up a contrast between the first and second blanks. We know from Step One that both are people who work with stars, and now we also know that they are different kinds of people.     
}
\end{minipage} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know I can manually add space with '\vpsace' for instance, but the result is often not pretty.

Comment: And which is the question here?

Comment: I think the problem is related to: [Why is \parskip zero inside a minipage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64982/why-is-parskip-zero-inside-a-minipage).  I think you can take it out of `tikz` and see the same problem in a `minipage`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is not related to `tikz` but is an issue with `minipage`.

In a `minipage`, the parameters `\parskip` and `\parindent` seem to be reset.
So you can adapt the solution from [How to preserve the same parskip in minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43002/how-to-preserve-the-same-parskip-in-minipage) to define a `minipageparskip` environment which preserves the `\parskip` and `\parindent`.  Here is a before (in red) and after comparison:

[image]

### References:

- [Why is \parskip zero inside a minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64982/why-is-parskip-zero-inside-a-minipage)
- [How to preserve the same parskip in minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43002/how-to-preserve-the-same-parskip-in-minipage)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,backgrounds,arrows}   
\usepackage{tabularx}
\tikzset{mybox/.style= {draw=black,fill=black!5,thick,rectangle,rounded corners,inner xsep=40pt, inner ysep=14pt}}


\newlength{\currentparskip}
\newlength{\currentparindent}
\newenvironment{minipageparskip}[2][]
  {\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value
    \setlength{\currentparindent}{\parindent}%
   \begin{minipage}[#1]{#2}% open the minipage
   \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value
   \setlength{\parindent}{\currentparindent}% restore the value
  }
  {\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\node [mybox,fill=red, fill opacity=0.2, text opacity=1] (box) { \begin{minipage}[t!]{0.75\textwidth}
Then we look for \textbf{clues}. 

Okay, this is a good time to find any direction words. Those are words that tell you how the two blanks are related.

Here's one: ``while.'' The word ``while'' sets up a contrast between the first and second blanks. We know from Step One that both are people who work with stars, and now we also know that they are different kinds of people.     
\end{minipage} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\node [mybox] (box) { \begin{minipageparskip}[t!]{0.75\textwidth}
Then we look for \textbf{clues}. 

Okay, this is a good time to find any direction words. Those are words that tell you how the two blanks are related.

Here's one: ``while.'' The word ``while'' sets up a contrast between the first and second blanks. We know from Step One that both are people who work with stars, and now we also know that they are different kinds of people.     
\end{minipageparskip} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will be using this for sure. As a side note, would there be any reason why I shouldn't use `\smallskip` to get a little extra vertical space? I don't remember, but I seemed to have read at some point that the `\_skip` commands should be avoided. Is this this true? Within this context of course.

Comment: @Calhistorian: You can use `\smallskip` if you want to have different spacing between individual paragraphs. But if you want all the paragraphs to have that spacing in this special environment you can simply use `\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}`.

Comment: @Calhistorian: However, before you go and start changing the value of `\parskip` everywhere you should review [Too much whitespace before lists when changing the \parskip length](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14764/too-much-whitespace-before-lists-when-changing-the-parskip-length/) as _changing `\parindent` and `\parskip` is considered as one of the "deadly sins" in l2tabu and should be avoided_.