# Have new lines after paragraphs but not after headings in LaTex?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, paragraphs

I wish to follow the convention of marking paragraph breaks with a line break as opposed to the LaTex default of an indent. However I do not wish to have a new line after section headings.

Previous questions have solved how to add line breaks after paragraphs e.g.:
[Have new line between paragraphs, no indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74170/have-new-line-between-paragraphs-no-indentation)
and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195908/latex-multiple-linebreaks

Other questions have solved how to remove linebreaks after headings e.g.
[Reducing spacing after headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53338/reducing-spacing-after-headings)

However when I combine these approaches the linebreaks after the paragraph override the commands removing the linebreaks from below the headings. How can both effects be achieved simultaneously?

To illustrate:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\parskip = 12pt plus 6pt minus 4pt

%Settings for the headings
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}
\section{This is a section}
Here is my first paragraph; it should appear directly below the section heading.

This is my second paragraph. there should be a line break before it and the one above.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 4 of the manual of the `titlesec` manual, description of the `\titlespacing` command:

> `<after-sep>` is the separation between title and text—vertical with
>   `hang`, `block`, and `display`, and horizontal with `runin`, `drop`,
>   `wrap` and `...margin`. By making the value negative, you may define
>   an effective space of less than `\parskip`.

So just do that:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus 6pt minus 4pt}

%Settings for the headings
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-\parskip}\relax
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-\parskip}\relax

\begin{document}

\section{This is a section}
Here is my first paragraph;
it should appear directly below the section heading.

This is my second paragraph;
there should be a line break before it and the one above.

\subsection{This is a subsection}
The first paragraph in the subsection.

The second paragraph.

The third paragraph.

\end{document}
```

The output I obtain is:

[image: Output of the code]