# Empty line between paragraphs

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r)

Adding an empty line between paragraphs does not work, `\newline` does not work , where I am returning back to the wrong `\\\\`, which is very frustrating. When skipping two lines it starts a paragraph...  [image]

```
\documentclass[]{report} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\section{Software: Accessibility and Usability Evaluation}

\url{www.universaldesign.ie/useandapply/ict/\\itaccessibilityguidelines/applicationsoftware/guidelines}

There are three marks available for each product:

(1-3 where 0 is not applicable, 1 is not supported, 2 partially supported, 
3 – not supported) 

Please note that NVDA not used for software evaluation for fairness, as both pc applications 
and OS accessibility centre must be mutually compatible and will be the first entry point 
for the user.
```

Comment: \setlength{\parskip}{7pt} % 1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} found these lines in previous projects, which does make it work, but it feels like tweaking again. I want default behavior to support two spaces line break.

Comment: AFAIK, an empty line will always start a new paragraph. It is not clear what you are trying to do.
Also try to use the normal nomenclature. A *package* is something that you use with `\usepackage`. An *editor* is TeXStudio, TeXMaker, TeXWorks, etc. A *distribution* is the collection of software that creates the document from your code.

Comment: AFAIK, an empty line within the TexStudio starts a new paragraph but does not separate two paragraphs with an empty line, so it is very clear what I am trying to do, everything else are details which you can edit and I would approve. Basically, the way it is indented in the code. should appear as a result.

Comment: @Aubergine The behaviour of (La)TeX with respect to blank lines or anything else has nothing to do with the editor you use. In your code snippet, you have five paragraphs and a section heading, and that's also what you seem to have in your picture. Perhaps you are looking for blank lines between paragraphs, in which you want `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` in your preamble, at least if you are not using the KOMA-Script or `memoir` classes.

Comment: @Aubergine a new line starts a new paragraph. If this is visualized by an indentation of the first line of the new paragraph or a more or less wide space between the paragraphs (in word often achieved by adding an empty line) is just a question of the markup you or your documentclass chose.

Comment: @JosephWright Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. I will update question, tags etc..

Comment: @Aubergine Maybe you could also delete the references to texstudio in the question title and rephrase the question itself to clarify that it is not related to texstudio at all.

Comment: Also, perhaps unrelated (?), I noticed that you included a ``\\`` in your `\url`. Was you trying to insert a line-break? If so, note that the result is not what you expected, since a ``\`` appears at the place where you put ``\\``