# How should I do manual line breaks?

Tags: line-breaking

How do I break lines manually?

Methods I use:

```
\linebreak
\\
\n
```

Which is the recommended one?

**Example:**

If I just put like this in my tex file,

```
This is for people who love VIM and for people who hate VIM.

Some of you may be wondering what VIM is...

Here you go...
```

the output is

```
This is for people who love VIM and for people who hate VIM.
Some of you may be wondering what VIM is...
Here you go...
```

But I want it to show

```
This is for people who love VIM and for people who hate VIM.

Some of you may be wondering what VIM is...

Here you go...
```

**Update 2**

Can I use `\\[2cm]` for vertical spacing?

Comment: It's recommended not to use line breaks in normal text at all. Some line-oriented environments like `tabular` define `\\ ` in a special way, so that's what should be used in there.

Comment: Also, `\n` is not a line break at all for (La)TeX: the nearest equivalent would be `\linebreak`, but as @StephanLehmke comments you normally should not be using it.

Comment: @JosephWright Right, `\n` is only applicable in `tabular` environment.

Comment: It looks like you are wanting 'blank lines' (whitespace) between paragraphs: see [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42).

Comment: These are called paragraphs! Just leave a blank line between them.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Yeah, it works, when I have `\paragraph`. Is there anyway to create a paragraph without a title?

Comment: @ATOzTOA `\paragraph` is a sectioning command, like `\section`, but just happens by default not to alter the style of the text used as its argument.  A paragraph is just a series of lines divided by a blank line (or explicitly ended using `\par`).

Comment: @JosephWright When I just use `\paragraph` it makes the first character big, can I avoid this?

Comment: @ATOzTOA As I said, `\paragraph` is a _sectioning_ command and does not 'create a paragraph'. It's used in the form `\paragraph{title}` and comes 'below' `\subsubsection`. You almost certainly do not want `\paragraph`.

Comment: @JosephWright OK, so it is not what I need then. Back to my problem, how do I add blank lines between lines?

Comment: `\usepackage{parskip}`, as in the question Joseph linked to?

Comment: \newline  (these words are to get to 15 characters in length)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Stupid me, it works like a charm... thanks

Comment: @ATOzTOA by default `\n` is not defined at all in LaTeX it isn't applicable to `tabular` or anything else. If you do not get an error message you must be defining it locally.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh yeah, I am defining it... thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to this for the whole document, then the `parskip` package is probably the best option.  As Joseph Wright says, the question [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r) deals with this well.

If it is just for some individual lines where you want the extra space then there are other options.  You can use one of `\smallskip`, `\medskip` or `\bigskip` or their break equivalents `\smallbreak` etc.  Or you can load the `setspace` package that provides a double space environment.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\paragraph*{Normal}

This is for people who love VIM and for people who hate VIM.  

Some of you may be wondering what VIM is\dots  

Here you go\dots  

\paragraph*{medskips}

This is for people who love VIM and for people who hate VIM.  

\medskip
Some of you may be wondering what VIM is\dots  

\medskip
Here you go\dots

\begin{doublespace}
\paragraph*{Double space}

This is for people who love VIM and for people who hate VIM.  

Some of you may be wondering what VIM is\dots  

Here you go\dots  
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

I you wish to remove the indentation at the beginning of a paragraphs, then you can issue `\noindent` on each occaision, or `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` globally or e.g. inside the `doublespace` environment.

Should wish to specify the vertical gaps in sizes other than those provided by the skip commands, then latex has the `\vspace` command used as `\vspace{2cm}`.

Here is an illustration of both points:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\noindent
This is for people who love VIM and for people who hate VIM.  

\medskip\noindent
Some of you may be wondering what VIM is\dots  

\vspace{2cm}\noindent
Here you go\dots

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{doublespace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

This is for people who love VIM and for people who hate VIM.  

Some of you may be wondering what VIM is\dots  

Here you go\dots  
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

If you are using the one of the koma classes or memoir, then they include other commands for this type of situation.

Comment: Paragraph will work, but I don't want the title or the indent.

Comment: @Andrew I'd be tempted to use `\section` rather than `\paragraph`, partly as people misunderstand it and partly as you'd normally start with `\section` divisions in the `article` class.

Comment: @JosephWright I have added second example without the headings.

Comment: I have an issue, when i use `parskip`, the `tabular` environment gets a let of vertical space before and after. Anyway I can disable parskip for `tabular` alone?

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question.