# \usepackage{parskip} and \tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, parskip

As I had issue with line breaks, [How should I do manual line breaks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96827/how-should-i-do-manual-line-breaks), I used `\usepackage{parskip}`.

This worked fine.

But, when I have a tabular environment, there is a lot of vertical spacing before and after the enviroment.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1]{\texttt{\small\color{blue}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\n}[0]{\\[3mm]}

\begin{document}

This is a line.

This a new paragraph.

\subsubsection{Closing Windows}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{p{10mm}p{40mm}p{80mm}}
1 & dskhkdfahsk & khskdahfkhk\n
2 & two & three\n
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}

Hello1

Hello2

\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can disable `parskip` for `tabular` alone?

Comment: Don't use this flushright-environment. Like center it will add additional space. And please stop to sent code snippets. That's quite impolite as it makes helping more difficult  - even more if this code snippets use nonstandard commands and so can't be compile with a standard preamble without errors.

Comment: Just use `{\raggedleft\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}\par}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I used this:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\dimexpr\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 20pt\relax}
```

After a lot of experimentation with the `plus` and `minus` values, I got it working.

Comment: I don't think this is a solution. Try this: `\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 20pt}
\def\test{abc\par}
\def\testa{\test\test\test\test\test}
\def\testb{\testa\testa\testa\testa\testa}
\def\testc{\testb\testb}
\begin{document}
\testc
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your example comes from the width of the tabular.  For illustration consider the following sequence of `flushright` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
  \rule{2cm}{0.4pt}
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushright}
  \rule{5cm}{0.4pt}
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushright}
  \rule{10cm}{0.4pt}
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushright}
  \rule{15cm}{0.4pt}
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushright}
  \rule{2cm}{0.4pt}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

producing

[image: Sample rule outputs]

You'll see that there is extra vertical space before the line that is wider than text width.

In your example, the tabular has width `130mm` plus the intercolumn spacing and the log file tells you that the line is overfull by `60.8858pt`.  Reducing the dimension of say the last column, the anomolous spacing disappears:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1]{\texttt{\small\color{blue}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\n}[0]{\\[3mm]}

\begin{document}

This is a line.

This a new paragraph.

\subsubsection{Closing Windows}

\begin{flushright}
  \begin{tabular}{p{10mm}p{40mm}p{30mm}}
    1 & dskhkdfahsk & khskdahfkhk\n
    2 & two & three\n
  \end{tabular}
\end{flushright}

Hello1

Hello2

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

`flushright` adds some extra vertical spacing (`\topsep`, standard value `8pt plus 2pt minus 4t`, but set to `0pt` by the `parskip` package), but this on its own is not as dramitic as what you were seeing, unless the contents are overwide.

`flushright` acts like this because it is defined as

```
\trivlist \raggedleft\item\relax
```

which creates something akin to

```
\hfill\strut\hskip 0pt
```

on the first line.  LaTeX then finds an allowable break point at the `\hskip`, and when the line is overfull, can choose to break there.