# vspace equivalent of newline

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I am writing one report using LaTeX and R. I just found `\vspace` can be used for `\newline`. May I know how much `\vspace` == `\newline`?

```
 \vspace{x cm} = \newline
  x = ?
```

Comment: For what do you need `\newline` anyway? You should use an empty input line or `\par` to denote a new paragraph. If you want to use paragraph spacing instead of indention, you may look at the [`parskip` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) (→ [How should I do manual line breaks?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96827)) or the appropriate ways to do this with KOMA-Script or `memoir`. Anyways, you are probably looking for `\vspace{\baselineskip}` …

Comment: This is a better question/answer on that matter: [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42) If these answers do not apply to your use-case, you will need to provide more information: Class? MWE? What has R to do with it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is no such relationship between `\vspace` and  `\newline`!

### `\vspace` semantics

- in vertical mode (between paragraphs) `\vspace` adds an additional vertical space as defined by the argument
- in horizontal mode (within a paragraph) `\vspace` adds an additional vertical space between lines **after the end of the current line**, i.e., it doesn't act on the current point in the paragraph unless that happens to be a natural line break by chance.
- in either case the extra space with be dropped if it falls into a page break (`\vspace*` in contrast keeps the space always).

### `\newline` semantics

- in vertical mode `\newline` simply generates and error: "! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end."
- in horizontal mode it ends the current line at the current point and starts a new one.
- if two `\newline` commands come directly after each other they result in an empty line but with an additional warning message: "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at..." so this is not necessarily the best way to generate empty lines.

The command `\\` works (in most environments) similar to `\newline` but allows to specify an optional argument that defines the extra space that should be added after the current line. Thus in a normal paragraph `\\[\baselineskip]` would generate an empty line and so would `\vspace{\baselineskip}\linebreak`. Notice that the `\vspace`has to come first, otherwise it would apply not after the line with the linebreak but one line later!

Comment: I wish the OP would uncheck my answer and check yours :(

Comment: @Jubobs don't worry. seems good enough to link in your answer to mine for details

Comment: I want an empty line between tabulars. If I use `\\ ` or `\linebreak` I get an error "There's no line here to end". So the only good solution for me is `\vspace{\baselineskip}`.

Comment: @JHBonarius this is not the right place for questions, but to answer yours: nobody ever said that \vspace is not useful: in vertical mode between paragraphs it is a good way to add a specific amount of vertical space.