# Problem creating 2 subsections within the same section

Tags: errors

I have a document Latex that contains many sections. In a given section I want to create two subsections that contain each different subparagraphs. I don't know why I get an error when compiling it (! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.\par \subsection)?
Here is my code:

```
 \section{ Title}
 \subsection{subsection 1}
 \paragraph{~\newline}
 \subparagraph{ first subparagraph}
 \subparagraph{... (something between parenthesis)}
 \subparagraph{4 choices::
 \begin{itemize}
  \item 1.
  \item 2.
  \item 3.    
  \item 4.
 \end{itemize}
 }
 \subsection{subsection 2}
 \paragraph{~\newline}
 \subparagraph{1}
 \subparagraph{2}
 \subparagraph{ 3 .... here I include two parenthesis because I have them in my     original paragraph \left(something\right)}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1.    
\item 2.
\end{itemize}
}
```

Could you please help me ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please complete your code to make it a complete, small document. Try deleting `\paragraph{~\newline}`.

Comment: Not to mention the `itemize` pretending to be `enumerate` within `\subsection`… I would *really* recommend reading an introduction to LaTeX.  [The Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) is a pretty solid reference.  After you read that, I'd also recommend something a little more up-to-date (like `texdoc lshort`).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem arises from trying to include an environment inside a sectioning command.  LaTeX is *not* XML – don't pretend it is!  It's a common mistake, but a critical one.

You have a ton of other problems in this document – at this point, it isn't really salvageable.  Work from this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Some Section}
Text text text

% I personally have never found a use for \(sub)paragraph,
% but this is how I'd use it.
\subparagraph{Introductory sentence.}
Text text text.

\subparagraph{We have four choices.}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Option
\item Option
\item Option    
\item Option
\end{enumerate}

\section{Some Other Section}

\subparagraph{Intro sentence.}
Text text text

Paragraphs are created by empty lines in your source file.

See?  That was much easier!

\begin{itemize}
\item Use `enumerate' for ordered lists.
\item Use `itemize' for \emph{unordered} lists.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I'll note that those *are* separate paragraphs being created at the end.  Since `\parskip` is zero and each of the paragraphs are one line, they are aligned together at `\parindent`.  Make the paragraphs longer and you'll see what I mean.  There are other questions on this site that are concerned with [adding space between paragraphs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57/17423).

Comment: I tried this because I want subsection 1 and subsection2 to appear in the table of contents as two subsection. Is there a way to do this with do way you did with subparagraphs ?

Comment: I do not understand what you say – I am sorry. `:(` You can try `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}`.  That will include five levels in the table of contents.  You can also try using different sectioning commands: `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph`, and `\subparagraph`.  I do recommend reading a LaTeX tutorial – there are tutorials in many languages.