# Separating some paragraphs with a blank line, and other paragraphs without a blank line?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I want to be able to write blocks of paragraphs that share the same idea like this.

__1. This a a sentence about something. I continue with another sentence. With this sentence I conclude an idea, and a new paragraph is needed.

__2. I start another short paragraph here, but I did not leave a blank line between both paragraphs, because they talk about the same general idea. With this sentence I end that general idea and my paragraph.

__3. Now I am talking about some other stuff that is not related to the previous idea, but does not need a new section. I want to have a blank line between both paragraphs.

The __ is an indentation, and the paragraphs are numbered. Right now I have what is shown here; there is a blank line between all paragraphs, but I do not want that blank line between paragraph 1 and 2.

Right now I am using \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip} to get a new line between paragraphs, but I can't seem to find a way to not have that blank line between certain paragraphs.

Is there some easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Wouldn't an itemize list  fit your needs?

Comment: Are you talking about blank lines in the source code or in the output PDF? What document class are you using? Please provide a minimal working example so we know how we can help.

Comment: If you need to insert extra space between non-numbered paragraphs and also start them with no indent, than `\bigskip \noindent` should do it. There are different sizes of skips, pick one that fits.

Comment: Perhaps you're describing the use of a blank line as a kind of empty section header, to set off a new block of writing. In that case, `\newcommand{\newthought}{\par\vspace*{\baselineskip}}` or something like that.

Comment: @ajeh `\usepackage{parskip}` accomplishes the same thing. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r

Comment: @AndrewCashner It might, but knowing too many packages that do the same as a couple of standard macros is kind of taxing on the brain :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `\medskip` (or `\bigskip`), that's all.

```
This a a sentence about something. I continue with another sentence. With
this sentence I conclude an idea, and a new paragraph is needed.

I start another short paragraph here, but I did not leave a blank line
between both paragraphs, because they talk about the same general idea. With
this sentence I end that general idea and my paragraph.

\medskip

Now I am talking about some other stuff that is not related to the previous
idea, but does not need a new section. I want to have a blank line between 
both paragraphs.
```

***Don't*** set `\parskip` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following might help:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\specialparshook}{}% Hook for start of environment
\newcommand{\specialparsitemhook}{}% Hook for start of item inside environment
\newenvironment{specialpars}
  {\setcounter{enumi}{0}% Restart counter
   \specialparshook% Environment hook
   \renewcommand{\item}{%
     \specialparsitemhook% Item hook
     \leavevmode% Start new paragraph
     \refstepcounter{enumi}% Increment counter
     \theenumi.~% Print numbering
   }}{}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\connectpars}{\vspace{-\parskip}}

\begin{document}
I want to be able to write blocks of paragraphs that share the same idea like this.

\begin{specialpars}
  \item\label{par1}
  This a a sentence about something. I continue with another sentence. With this sentence I conclude an idea, 
  and a new paragraph is needed.

  \connectpars

  \item\label{par2}
  I start another short paragraph here, but I did not leave a blank line between both paragraphs, 
  because they talk about the same general idea. With this sentence I end that general idea and my paragraph.

  \item
  Now I am talking about some other stuff that is not related to the previous idea, but does not need a new 
  section. I want to have a blank line between both paragraphs.
\end{specialpars}

The \rule{1em}{.4pt} is an indentation, and the paragraphs are numbered. Right now I have what is shown here; 
there is a blank line between all paragraphs, but I do not want that blank line between paragraph~\ref{par1} 
and~\ref{par2}.

Right now I am using \verb|\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}| to get a new line between paragraphs, but I 
can't seem to find a way to not have that blank line between certain paragraphs.

Is there some easy way to achieve this?
\end{document}
```

The idea is to create a list-like environment. with every idea being set with an `\item`. Paragraphs (or `\item`s) are connected with `\connectpars`, which jumps back vertically by `\parskip`.

Other hooks are provided, if needed, although they weren't used in this example. Note that it would not be possible to include an `enumerate` within this list since it uses `enumi` - the first-level counter for `enumerate`. Of course, that can be changed.