# Hspace* at each linebreak

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

Here a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I don't want to use hspace* all the time. Is there any possibility to let LaTex make a hspace (like in Word) at each new line instead of making a parindent? It's easy to stop the parindent, but I would like to make the space too.

Kind regards!

Comment: You need to set `\parskip`. The [`parskip` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) can help, the KOMA classes have options to deal with that natively.

Comment: Very possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42/35864)

Comment: It’s not that clear what your asking, could you pleas clarify by adding at least a screenshot of how it should look like? I posted an answer but, but I’m guessing though …

Comment: i'm a little confused here.  `\hspace*` is a horizontal space, which you say you don't want, at least at the beginning of a paragraph.  do you really mean you want a vertical space between paragraphs, or do you want paragraphs to begin with an unindented line, followed by continuation lines that *are* indented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not exactly sure what you mean by “space at each line break” so here are there possible ways to mar a paragraph’s begin.

[image: differnet par markings]

## 1. Parindent

The most common way is indenting the first line of each paragraph, except it is preceded by a headline. This way is the preferred way, because it is also visible at a page break or after an equation, list etc. while the parskip becomes invisible in such cases.

Since this is also LaTeXs default (at least in the most classes) you don’t have to do anything.

## 2. Parskip

Another option is to leave some vertical space between paragraphs. This can be done by hand using

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

but I suggest using the package `parskip` since it also cares for lists or if you using a KOMA-Script class, the `parskip` option.

## 3. Hang indent

A rather unusual way is to outdent the first line or indent all lines except the first, which can be done with

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\everypar{\setlength{\hangindent}{1em}}
```

But this should be handled with care and is not really advisable.

---

**Full Code**

```
\documentclass[
%   parskip = full,% better than setting the skip manually!
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% In a real document you should never mix different types and
% the settings should be made in the preamble.

\begin{document}

\section{Normal Indent}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{No Indent: Skip between pars}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
% It is better to use the parskip package or
% KOMA-Script’s parskip-Option!
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Hang Indent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\everypar{\setlength{\hangindent}{1em}}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Although I did for the example image these different versions should *not* be mixed in a single document!

Comment: @cfr: Thanks for your comment! I fixed the typo and added a full MWE.