# Inserting new paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs

I want to make a new paragraph, but when I try to put some text, and then a blank line in my code, it gives me a BadBox error. How can I make paragraphs with the following format, without receiving BB errors?

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
>
> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

The following is only a snippet from my code, as each of the sections are identical, and all produce the same BB error:

```
\begin{document}    
\section{Fermat's Last Theorem}
The question of Fermat's Last Theorem has puzzled mathematicians for centuries. The problem, although simple to state, was a beast the likes of which people had never seen. For many years, this problem remained unsolved. \newline \newline
\noindent The hypothesis was as follows:
For $n,x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$, the equation $x^n+y^n=z^n$ has no solutions. Equivalently, using the theorem's connection to elliptic curves, the theorem can be stated as: If $a,b,c$ is a non-trivial solution to $x^p+y^p=z^p$ where $p$ is an odd prime number, then $y^2 = x(x-a^p)(x+b^p)$ will be an elliptic curve.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also, since lorim ipsum is a made up language LaTeX has no hyphenation patthers for it. You can use the `kantlipsum` package and its `\kant` macro to generate sample text in English. But as Stefan notes, please make a MWE, so we can see what you are doing

Comment: To remove the bad box, replace `\newline \newline` with a literal blank line in your source file. The `\noindent` command will unfortunately make it difficult to see where the second paragraph starts, as the LaTeX default is to use no additional spacing between paragraphs.

Comment: @MikeRenfro But how do I make it so that there are gaps between paragraphs and no bad box errors?

Comment: See [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r)

Comment: you should almost never have `\noindent` or `\newline` in a document and never `\newline\newline`

Comment: If you want paragraphs, use paragraphs (indicated in TeX with a blank line). If you use `\newline\newline` you're explicitly telling TeX to continue typesetting in the same paragraph instead of starting a new one.