# Why are some paragraphs indented and others aren't

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I've got this little problem. Page one shows my paragraphs the way I want them to look but starting from the second page, they all start to indent for some reason and I don't want that. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\author{Mout Pessemier, Bram Vanoverbeke}
\title{IT2Business}
\date{\today}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{opdracht1.bib}
\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \flushbottom
    %\thispagestyle{empty}

 \section{Opdracht}
    Maak een samenvatting van 3 pagina's rond de ITIL services zoals Incident Management Process, Problem Management Process en Change Management Process.

%    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}
%        \label{wrap-fig:1}
%        \includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{ITILCircle.jpg}
%        \caption{ITIL Service Strategy}
%    \end{wrapfigure}

    \section{ITIL}

    ITIL staat voor Information Technology Infrastructure Library en is ontworpen om het beheren van (IT-)processen binnen een organisatie te vereenvoudigen. Het is een set van best practices, geen framework met bepaalde regels waaraan je verwacht wordt te voldoen. Het draait allemaal rond het begrip service management waarbij de nadruk wordt gelegd op het opleveren van een zo hoog mogelijke waarde voor de klant.

    \subsection{Verschillende versies}
    ITIL heeft al enkele fasen doorstaan. Op dit moment is de recentste fase V4. Elke fase is een verbetering van de vorige.

    \section{Change Management}

     Change management houdt zich bezig met de systematische veranderingen binnen een organisatie. Hierbij zorgen we ervoor dat dit niet overwacht is, maar dat we alle veranderingen inplannen en op voorhand aankondigen. We houden hierbij niet alleen rekening met onszelf maar ook met de andere delen van de organisatie waar een welbepaalde verandering invloed op zou kunnen hebben. We gaan de eventuele problemen dat deze verandering met zich mee brengt gaan analyseren en zo snel en goed mogelijk oplossen.
     \newline
     \newline
     Dus de missie van change management is om veranderingen te implementeren op de meest effeciënte manier, zodat de klant het minst mogelijk aantal problemen heeft tijdens de veranderingen. Change management houdt ook nog een aantal dingen bij om te zien hoe succesvol de veranderingen zijn.

     \begin{enumerate}
         \item Succesvolle veranderingen: Het aantal veranderingen die goed zijn verlopen vergeleken met het totaal aantal veranderingen.
         \item Backlog van veranderingen: Het aantal veranderingen die nog niet voltooid zijn, het nummer hangt natuurlijk af van de grootte van de organisatie, maar zou eigelijk niet meer mogen groeien.
         \item Veranderingen bij nood: Aantal veranderingen die bij noodgevallen gebeuren, het nummer hangt ook weer af van de grootte van de organisatie, maar zou ook niet meer mogen groeien.
     \end{enumerate}

     \autocite{Onl3}


     \section{Incident Management}

     Incident management gaat over het melden en het zo snel mogelijk oplossen van incidenten. Een incident is een ongeplande onderbreken of vermindering van de kwaliteit van een service die vastgelegd is in een Service Level Agreement (SLA).
     \newline
     \newline
     Incident Management staat meestal dicht bij de helpdesk, het eerste contactpunt tussen de gebruikers en de IT. Er wordt niet verwacht bij Incident Management om een gedetailleerde analyse te geven van het probleem, het zorgt meestal voor een snelle oplossing die tijdelijk gebruikt wordt. Er zijn enkele belangrijke hulpmiddelen zoals de (KEDB) Known Error Database, wat wordt onderhouden door de Problem Management, en het incident model. Het incident model is een opgesteld plan over welke stappen men moet nemen tijdens een probleem.
     \autocite{Onl1}

    \section{Problem Management}

     Problem management is een stap verder in de levenscyclus van een service. Bij probleem management gaat men niet alleen een tijdelijke oplossing proberen zoeken voor een probleem (Een probleem is een incident dat meerdere malen voorkomt), maar gaat men op zoek naar de oorzaak van het probleem om dit voor eens en altijd uit de service proberen weg te werken. Probleem management's eerste taak is het diagnostiseren van het probleem en het zoeken van een tijdelijke fix om de service terug aan het werk te krijgen. Op het probleem te weten te komen wordt meestal gebruik gemaakt van een 'Known Error DataBase (KEDB)' waarin de meest vookomende fouten worden in opgeslagen. Nadat het probleem geïdentificeerd is, moet er een oplossing gezocht worden.

     Probleem management omvat:
     \begin{enumerate}
         \item probleem opsporing
         \item probleem logging
         \item probleem prioritisering
         \item probleem diagnose
         \item probleem oplossing
         \item ...
     \end{enumerate}
    \autocite{Onl2}

    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

content of opdracht1.bib:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{Art1,
  author       = {Stephen Watts},
  title        = {ITIL V2 vs ITIL V3: What’s the Difference?},
  journal      = {bmc blogs},
  journaltitle = {bmc blogs},
  year         = {2017},
  date         = {2017-05-30},
}

@Online{Onl1,
  author = {bcm},
  editor = {bcm},
  title  = {ITIL incident management 101},
  year   = {2016},
  date   = {2016-12-22},
  url    = {https://www.bmc.com/guides/itil-incident-management.html},
}

@Online{Onl2,
  author = {bcm},
  editor = {bcm},
  title  = {What is problem management?},
  year   = {2016},
  date   = {2016-12-22},
  url    = {https://www.bmc.com/guides/itil-problem-management.html},
}

@Online{Onl3,
  author = {bcm},
  editor = {bcm},
  title  = {ITIL change management 101},
  year   = {2016},
  date   = {2016-12-22},
  url    = {https://www.bmc.com/guides/itil-change-management.html},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:biblatex;}
```

As you can see, the distance isn't the same, I prefer the shorter distance if possible
[image]

Comment: Don't use `\newline\newline` (or ```\\```) to end a paragraph, just leave a blank line. Other than that note that some document classes don't indent the first paragraph after a section heading. If I change from `\newline\newline` to a blank line instead I get the output I expected, but I'm not quite sure if that is what you want to see. In particular the first page has no paragraphs that don't follow a section heading and so it is not quite clear what output you want to see on page 2 where there are paragraphs that don't follow a heading.

Comment: Note for future questions (it is not that relevant here) that a screenshot of your `.bib` file as opened in JabRef is next to useless for us. We would have to copy the text from the screenshot manually to make use of it. A `.bib` file is just a normal text file and so you can just open it with a text editor and paste the relevant contents to your question. (As I said before, you probably don't have to do that now because the citations are hardly relevant for the paragraph indentations, but if you ask questions where citations are relevant in the future, please keep that in mind.)

Comment: @moewe I've added the jabref in txt

Comment: Ah! You use the option `twoside` for two-sided printing. That means that the margins on even and odd pages are mirrored (just as they are in a book) so that the outer margins are wider than the inner margins. If you want one-sided printing you can remove the `twoside` option and the margins on all pages should be the same.

Comment: @moewe I was about writing an answer with exactly this statement. Go ahead and make you r comment an answer.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot! (how do I accept your asnwer now?)

Comment: @AlexG Please don't let my comment stop you from writing a proper answer.

Comment: @moewe It would have consisted of one sentence only.

Comment: @AlexG So would mine, but OK, let me write something up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect we are seeing is not the paragraph indentation, it is the margin of the page.

The option `twoside` enables two-sided printing for your document. Among other things (that mainly have to do with headers) the option also changes the margin settings so that the margins are reversed on even and odd pages. That way you get wide outer margins and smaller inner margins if you read your two-sided document like a book.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: two-sided document with wide outer margins]

If you want the margins to be the same on all pages (even or odd), you should not use the `twoside` option (instead you want `oneside`, which is the default for `article`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: one-sided document with same margins on all pages]

`twoside` usually looks nicer with longer documents that are printed and bound two-sided. Shorter documents that are printed one-sided or documents that are only read on screen usually look nicer with `oneside` since that avoids the jump at the margins.

---

Please note that paragraphs should always be ended with a blank line (or `\par`) as in

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

and not with `\\` or `\newline` or `\newline\newline`. If you don't like that subsequent paragraphs are indented and would rather see them set apart from the previous paragraphs with some vertical space you may want to look into the `parskip` package or into `memoir` or the KOMA-classes. See [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42/35864).