# Underline without Indentation

Tags: underline

How do you underline in LaTeX without indentation? I am using the \underline command:

CODE:

```
So then Black History Month for All Americans is a time to remember, a time to dream and a time to rededicate ourselves to the concept of brotherhood, fair play, and equity for Blacks in our respective community.

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\underline{First Let Us Remember}

We should remember that America was the first nation in the history of the world to be founded with a purpose. This purpose is set forth not only in the historical documents though which the birth of this nation was proclaimed as in the statements, ``all men are created equal" and ``Governments [deriving their just powers from the] consent of the governed."\footnote{``The Declaration of Independence: The Want, Will, and Hopes of the People." 4 July 1776, Independence Hall Association, \url{https://www.ushistory.org/declaration/document/.}} but also in the will and the soul of its people as exemplifies by such statements as:
```

**The problem with the PDF file is that First Let Us Remember is always indented. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `\noindent\underlina{...}`. But *don't* use underlining. Use italic or boldface for emphasis.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. The \noindent\underline{ . . } worked - First Let Us Remember is no longer indented; however, there is no line space between First Let Us Remember and We should remember. Inserting another \vspace{\baselineskip} does not work.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r for some approaches to set paragraph spacing.

Comment: If "First Let Us Remember" is a  kind of unnumbered title, is better use some like `\section*{}`, `\subsection*{}, etc.` that by default are not indented, take care of vertical spacing and more ... In standard classes these titles are not underlined but in boldface  that is better, but if you want it underlined, the right way is not avoid that commands, but redefine accordingly that commands to your style.

Comment: Marijn and Fran - Thank you both for your responses. The link on the \usepackage{parskip} was very helpful.

Comment: `\noindent\underline{...}\par\nopagebreak\medskip` would do. But it's probably better to follow advice and use `\section*`.

Comment: @user219671 `parskip` remove all the indentations (not only in the titles) and add vertical skips after all the paragraphs (not only in the title). Ideally the command of a title should not depend on  the global  paragraph settings.

Comment: @fran - Thank you for the info.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved with the comments.