# Line Break Issue using LaTeX

Tags: line-breaking

It seems that I've run into this line break issue. I've read to break lines using empty lines, but when I did so, the following issue occurred:

[image]

Despite breaking lines by pressing enter twice, this always gives me the issue of having a weird indent. Using `\\` seems to work; however, I've been told it's not good practice to do so. I'd like to know if there are any ways to remedy this problem or other alternatives to use without having to resort to using `\\` to break lines.

Thanks!

Comment: well that is the standard paragraph indentation. You can use e.g. the parskip package to use spaces between paragraphs instead.

Comment: Or, for those cases where you wish to avoid the indent, you can start with `\noindent` on the line.

Comment: I would not start removing the normal paragraph indentation. It is there for a reason, no indentation and no space between paraghraphs are horrible to read and one can never be 100% sure when a new paragraph starts. Then indentation enables us to know for sure when there is a new paragraph.

Comment: You need to ask yourself, "what is the purpose of forcing a line break, if not for a paragraph boundary?"  The answer to this might help guide the appropriate solution approach to your dilemma.  As an example, input format and output format can be distinct.  I break (not double-empty-line-paragraph-break)) each sentence onto a new line in my input for organizing my text editing.  However, in the typeset output, it formats continuously.

Comment: indenting the start of a paragraph has been standard practice since before printing was invented, why do you decribe it as "weird" ?

Comment: If you want paragraphs separated by empty lines in your whole document then you can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r. However, as others have commented, separating paragraphs by an indent (and no empty line) is used in many scientific texts but also novels etc., that's why it is the default in LaTeX.

Comment: Using \\ to force a line break is the wrong way to go. It'll force a line break all right, but it doesn't create a *paragraph* break, at least not in the TeX/LaTeX sense of the word. As @UlrikeFischer has already noted in a comment, if you really can't stand indentations of the first lines of paragraphs, load the `parskip` package. BTW, loading that package will not only set `\parindent` to zero but also set `\parskip` -- the vertical whitespace between paragraphs -- to a positive number.

Comment: All variations of TeX (pdf/lua/xe/) typeset a complete paragraph at once to do the best job of line breaking. Lines in the same paragraph should only be separated by a single return. Leaving a blank line (i.e., two returns in a row) denotes the end of a paragraph. Traditionally the first line of a paragraph is indented and there is no extra vertical space between paragraphs; this can be changed.