# Changing format of paragraph skip for a 400-pages document

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I am writing a long LaTeX document using the `book` documentclass, and after having typed already almost 400 pages, I have decided I want to change the format for new paragraphs to be more similar to the letter style, meaning that instead of an indented line, I would like to have some vertical space between paragraphs (not as much as a whole line) and the new paragraph to begin without indentation.

I could do this by placing `\noindent` at the beginning of each paragraph, and maybe adjusting the space with `\vspace`, but I imagine there is a better way than doing this one paragraph at a time for over 400 pages...

Comment: `\usepackage{parskip}`. But, please, don't inflict pages full of white bands to your readers…

Comment: [Related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r?).

Comment: You might play with lettrine for a more classic look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do `\usepackage{parskip}`, but, please, compare the two images below: the shorter your paragraph, more white bands across the page will appear. Maybe good for a letter; for books, I strongly adverse it.

For the first image I commented out `\usepackage{parskip}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh boy, oh boy... I never really realized how bad paragraph skips actually look...

Comment: The white bands are good for eyes.

Comment: @user271232 I don't think so. And generations of typographers agree.

Comment: I really think that the default parskip is too much (something as double what it should be). With 5pt plus 1pt it's much better

Comment: Although, thinking a bit more, in a physical, two-sided book is a nonno, because it basically kills the alignment in the lines in a spread. I use it just for online documents.