Graph theory code issues
I'm new to Latex and have just spent many many hours on my first assignment trying to use it and after writing 10 pages I got an error and Overleaf only outputs a couple of lines of errors but now my code is littered with errors that were totally fine before. What I mean is, the code hasn't changed at all and looks fine but now I am getting many undefined control sequence errors and missing \begin{document} which shouldn't be the case. My code is below, any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, positioning, graphdrawing, trees, shapes, arrows}
\usegdlibrary{force}
 
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

 \begin{document}
 
\title{MTH3170 Assignment 1}
\author{Chris Amon}



\maketitle

\textbf{1. (a)} Draw five different trees, each with maximum degree 3 and at least five vertices. In each example, state the number of vertices of degree 1 and the number of vertices of degree 3.
\[ \text{[7 marks]} \]

\hfill

\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every node/.style={circle,draw}, level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}]
        \node [circle, draw] {a}
            child {node [circle, draw] {b}
                child {node [circle, draw] {f}}
                child {node [circle, draw] {c}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {e}}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {d}}
                }
            };
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\centering
\textbf{Tree 1}
\[
\Delta (G) = 3
\]
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 1 \} |$ = 4\\
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 3 \} |$ = 2\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every node/.style={circle,draw}, level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}]
        \node [circle, draw] {a}
            child {node [circle, draw] {b}
                child {node [circle, draw] {f}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {g}}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {h}}}
                child {node [circle, draw] {c}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {e}}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {d}}
                }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\centering
\textbf{Tree 2}
\[
\Delta (G) = 3
\]
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 1 \} |$ = 5\\
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 3 \} |$ = 3\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every node/.style={circle,draw}, level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}]
        \node [circle, draw] {a}
            child {node [circle, draw] {b}
                child {node [circle, draw] {c}}
                child {node [circle, draw] {d}}
                }
            child {node [circle, draw] {e}}
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\centering
\textbf{Tree 3}
\[
\Delta (G) = 3
\]
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 1 \} |$ = 3\\
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 3 \} |$ = 1\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every node/.style={circle,draw}, level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}]
        \node [circle, draw] {a}
            child {node [circle, draw] {b}
                child {node [circle, draw] {c}}
                child {node [circle, draw] {d}}
                }
            child {node [circle, draw] {e}
                child {node [circle, draw] {g}}
                child {node [circle, draw] {f}}}
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\centering
\textbf{Tree 4}
\[
\Delta (G) = 3
\]
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 1 \} |$ = 4\\
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 3 \} |$ = 2\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every node/.style={circle,draw}, level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}]
        \node [circle, draw] {a}
            child {node [circle, draw] {b}
                child {node [circle, draw] {f}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {g}
                        child {node [circle, draw] {h}}
                        child {node [circle, draw] {i}}}
                }
                child {node [circle, draw] {c}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {e}}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {d}}
                }
            };
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\centering
\textbf{Tree 5}
\[
\Delta (G) = 3
\]
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 1 \} |$ = 5\\
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 3 \} |$ = 3\\
\hfill\\
\quad
(b) Let \( T \) be an arbitrary tree with maximum degree 3. What is the relationship between the number of vertices of degree 1 and the number of vertices of degree 3 in \( T \)? Prove your answer using the handshaking lemma.
\[ \text{[7 marks]} \]\\
\hfill\\
\begin{align*}
\sum_{v \in V(G)} \deg_G(v) &= 2 \left| E(G) \right|
\\
\left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 1 \} \right| + \left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 2 \} \right|&= 2\left| E(G) \right|\\
+ \left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 3 \} \right| \\\\
\left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 1 \} \right| &= 2\left| E(G) \right| - \left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 2 \} \right|\\
 & - \left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 3 \} \right|
\hfill\\
\end{align*}

(c) Generalise the result for an arbitrary tree, by proving a formula for the number of vertices of degree 1 in terms \( n_3 \), where \( n_3 \) is the number of vertices with degree three (for \( d = 3,4,5,...\)).
\[ \text{[7 marks]} \]
\hfill\\
\begin{align*}
\left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 1 \} \right| &= 2\left| E(G) \right| - \sum_{v \in V(G)} \deg_G(v) -\left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 1 \} \right|\\
\hfill\\
\end{align*}

(d) A saturated hydrocarbon (also called alkane or paraffin) is a molecule formed from carbon and hydrogen atoms by adding bonds between atoms such that each carbon atom is in four bonds, each hydrogen atom is in one bond, and no sequence of bonds forms a cycle or network. What is the relationship between the number of carbon and hydrogen atoms?
\[ \text{[3 marks]} \]

\begin{align*}
    H &= 2C + 2
\end{align*}

\textbf{2.} For what values of $n$ does there exist a 5-regular graph with $n$ vertices? Prove your answer.\\
\[\text{[20 marks]}\]\\
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1.5cm} }
\begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
& $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$  \\ \hline
$1$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$2$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$3$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$4$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$5$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$6$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}\\
This is the base case, the complete graph, $K_6$. To be a 5-regular graph we must meet these 3 conditions:\\
\begin{enumerate}
    \item We must have 5 connections for each row and each column
    \item For each entry, $i \times j$ = $j \times i$
    \item There can be no connection for the $i=j$ entry. This causes a line of symmetry.
\end{enumerate}These conditions will only occur when the graph has an even number of vertices. Take the $7 \times 7$ graph below:
\vspace{1cm}\\
\begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
& $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$  \\ \hline
$1$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$2$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$3$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$4$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$5$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$6$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$7$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}\\
We can satisfy condition 3 easily enough however it is not possible to satisfy conditions 1 and 2 simultaneously
\hfill\\
\begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
& $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$2$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$3$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$4$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$5$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$6$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$7$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$8$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\vspace{1cm}\\
Since n cannot connect to itself we must have at least n=6 vertices. And since all $deg(v)=5$ the Handshaking Lemma becomes:\\
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{v \in V(G)} \deg_G(v) &= 2 \left| E(G) \right|\\
    n*5 &= 2\left| E(G) \right|\\
\end{align*}
And so:
\begin{align*}
    5 \mid \left| E(G) \right| & & 2 \mid n
\end{align*}
Where $n \geq 6$\\
Therefore:
\begin{align*}
    n &= 2k +4\\
    \left| E(G) \right| &= 5k + 10
\end{align*}
\vspace{1cm}\\
\textbf{3. (a)} Prove that for $k \geq 2$, for every tree $T$ with $k$ vertices, every graph $G$ with minimum degree at least $k - 1$ contains a subgraph isomorphic to $T$.\\
\[\text{[15 marks]}\]\\
Every graph, $G$, with $deg_{G}(v) \geq k-1$ will contain as a minimum a complete subgraph, $K_k \subseteq G$, with $k$ vertices. This is because every complete graph with $k$ vertices has $deg_{K_k}(v)=k-1$. The proof is below:\\
\begin{align*}
    K_k \text{ has } \binom{k}{2} \text{ edges}\\
    \text{By the handshaking lemma}\\
    \sum_{v \in V(G)} deg_{K_k}(v) &= 2 \left| E(G) \right|\\
    k*deg_{K_k}(v) &= 2\left| \frac{k!}{2!(k-2)!} \right|\\
    deg_{K_k}(v) &= \frac{(k-1)!}{(k-2)!}\\
    &= k-1
\end{align*}
For every tree, $T$, with $k$ vertices, there will exist a complete graph, $K_k \subseteq G$, with a subgraph that is isomorphic to $T$, that is $S_k \cong T$.\\
Seeing as the complete graph includes all connections between vertices we simply only need to delete the edges that are not found in $T$\\
This satisfies the conditions for a subgraph\\
\begin{align*}
    V(S_k)=V(K_k)\\
    E(S_k)\subseteq E(K_k)
\end{align*}
\\
Now as long as $|V(S_k)| = |V(T)|$ and $|E(S_k)| = |E(T)|$ and there is a bijection \[ \phi: V(S_k) \mapsto V(T) \]\\ such that $\forall$  $u,v \in V(S_k)$ $uv \in E(S_k)$ iff $\phi(u)\phi(v) \in E(T)$\\
\hfill\\
We have an isomorphism\\
\hfill\\
\textbf{(b)} Show that "$k - 1$" in part (a) is best possible for every $k \geq 2$.
\[\text{[5 marks]}\]

\textbf{4.} Apply the algorithm presented in lectures for finding an Eulerian circuit to the following multi-graph. Make choices so that at least three maximal trails are determined. Show all steps of the algorithm.
\[\text{[5 marks]}\]\\
First we check that every vertex has an even degree and positive degree\\
\begin{align*}
deg_G(1) &= 2 & deg_G(2) &= 6  & deg_G(3) &= 4\\
deg_G(4) &= 2 & deg_G(5) &= 6  & deg_G(6) &= 4\\
deg_G(7) &= 4 & deg_G(8) &= 6  & deg_G(9) &= 4\\
\end{align*}
Next we go through the algorithm\\
\hfill\\
C=(1)\\
choose $w=1$\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=-1.5]{1}
    \Vertex[x=2.25,y=0]{2}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=1.5]{3}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=3]{4}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=2.625]{5}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=1.875]{6}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=-1.875]{7}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=-2.625]{8}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{9}
    \Edge[](1)(2)
    \Edge[](1)(9)
    \Edge[](2)(3)
    \Edge[](2)(5)
    \Edge[](2)(6)
    \Edge[](2)(7)
    \Edge[](2)(8)
    \Edge[](3)(5)
    \Edge[](3)(7)
    \Edge[](3)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(9)
    \Edge[](5)(8)
    \Edge[](5)(9)
    \Edge[](6)(7)
    \Edge[](7)(8)
    \Edge[](8)(9)
    \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[bend right]
    \Edge[label=$b$](5)(6)
    \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[bend left]
    \Edge[label=$a$](5)(6)
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\hfill\\
M$=(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9)$ in G - E(C)\\
C=$(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9)$\\
Choose $w=2$\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=-1.5]{1}
    \Vertex[x=2.25,y=0]{2}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=1.5]{3}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=3]{4}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=2.625]{5}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=1.875]{6}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=-1.875]{7}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=-2.625]{8}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{9}
    \Edge[](2)(5)
    \Edge[](2)(6)
    \Edge[](2)(7)
    \Edge[](2)(8)
    \Edge[](3)(7)
    \Edge[](3)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(9)
    \Edge[](5)(8)
    \Edge[](5)(9)
    \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[bend left]
    \Edge[label=$a$](5)(6)
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\hfill\\
M$=(2,5,6)$ in G - E(C)\\
C=$(1,2,5,6,3,5,6,7,8,9)$\\
Choose $w=3$\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=-1.5]{1}
    \Vertex[x=2.25,y=0]{2}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=1.5]{3}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=3]{4}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=2.625]{5}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=1.875]{6}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=-1.875]{7}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=-2.625]{8}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{9}
    \Edge[](2)(7)
    \Edge[](2)(8)
    \Edge[](3)(7)
    \Edge[](3)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(9)
    \Edge[](5)(8)
    \Edge[](5)(9)
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\hfill\\
M$=(3,7,2,8,5,9,4,8)$ in G - E(C)\\
C=$(1,2,5,6,3,7,2,8,5,9,4,8,5,6,7,8,9)$\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=-1.5]{1}
    \Vertex[x=2.25,y=0]{2}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=1.5]{3}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=3]{4}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=2.625]{5}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=1.875]{6}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=-1.875]{7}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=-2.625]{8}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{9}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\hfill\\

\end{document}


If you get errors, you should always show the first error as a copy from the log-file. However, it seems you are using packages that are incompatible, because they define the same command. If I comment \usepackage{tkz-graph} the error message about already defined \VertexInnerSep vanishes and the file compiles without error message. So as usual I would recommend to load only those package, you are really using. Also note, that you need to use LuaLaTeX for this document, because of loading TikZ library graphdrawing.

I dont think I have any \VertexInnerSep in my code though

I've not said, that you have defined \VertexInnerSep. I've told you, that more than one package you are using define it and how to avoid this by removing at least one currently not used package. BTW: If you don't use the graphdrawing library, you can also remove this from the preamble. If you do so, the example would also run with PDFLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX.

BTW: Do you really want to use \centering for the whole document? If so, you don't need to repeat it several times. One \centering at the beginning should be enough. Using \hfill\\ to add empty lines is also not recommended. Maybe you want something like a vertical distance between paragraphs or change the vertical skip before and after displayed math. But this is not clear and would be another question.

Thanks for the \centering tip. With the \hfill\ what is the alternative?

This would be another question and the answer depends on what you are trying. If you want paragraph distance instead of paragraph intend → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-i-use-a-vertical-space-between-paragraphs-rather-than-indentation. If you just want a vertical distance, e.g., between some pictures or some elements on an title page or something like this → https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41488/277964

I can't reproduce your error, but get a different one.
1. Strategy to localize problems
What works quickly is:

commenting out (almost) everything (i.e. just leave for the compiler a rudimentary document)
compile (should work, OR until it works)
gradually uncomment and compile again
until you know what's wrong

Doing so with your code leaves it as shown below AND indicates a problem introduced by \usepackage{tkz-graph} % <<< ! LaTeX Error: Command \VertexInnerSep already defined. Leaving a few other things out, not needed for the code you show to compile, results in:

Please note I haven't checked necessity of all remaining packages in the code below.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{tkz-graph} % <<< ! LaTeX Error: Command \VertexInnerSep already defined.
%\usetikzlibrary{graphs, positioning, graphdrawing, trees, shapes, arrows}
%\usegdlibrary{force}
% 
%\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
%\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

 \begin{document}
 
\title{MTH3170 Assignment 1}
\author{Chris Amon}



\maketitle

\textbf{1. (a)} Draw five different trees, each with maximum degree 3 and at least five vertices. In each example, state the number of vertices of degree 1 and the number of vertices of degree 3.
\[ \text{[7 marks]} \]

\hfill

\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every node/.style={circle,draw}, level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}]
        \node [circle, draw] {a}
            child {node [circle, draw] {b}
                child {node [circle, draw] {f}}
                child {node [circle, draw] {c}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {e}}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {d}}
                }
            };
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\centering
\textbf{Tree 1}
\[
\Delta (G) = 3
\]
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 1 \} |$ = 4\\
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 3 \} |$ = 2\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every node/.style={circle,draw}, level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}]
        \node [circle, draw] {a}
            child {node [circle, draw] {b}
                child {node [circle, draw] {f}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {g}}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {h}}}
                child {node [circle, draw] {c}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {e}}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {d}}
                }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\centering
\textbf{Tree 2}
\[
\Delta (G) = 3
\]
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 1 \} |$ = 5\\
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 3 \} |$ = 3\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every node/.style={circle,draw}, level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}]
        \node [circle, draw] {a}
            child {node [circle, draw] {b}
                child {node [circle, draw] {c}}
                child {node [circle, draw] {d}}
                }
            child {node [circle, draw] {e}}
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\centering
\textbf{Tree 3}
\[
\Delta (G) = 3
\]
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 1 \} |$ = 3\\
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 3 \} |$ = 1\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every node/.style={circle,draw}, level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}]
        \node [circle, draw] {a}
            child {node [circle, draw] {b}
                child {node [circle, draw] {c}}
                child {node [circle, draw] {d}}
                }
            child {node [circle, draw] {e}
                child {node [circle, draw] {g}}
                child {node [circle, draw] {f}}}
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\centering
\textbf{Tree 4}
\[
\Delta (G) = 3
\]
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 1 \} |$ = 4\\
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 3 \} |$ = 2\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every node/.style={circle,draw}, level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}]
        \node [circle, draw] {a}
            child {node [circle, draw] {b}
                child {node [circle, draw] {f}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {g}
                        child {node [circle, draw] {h}}
                        child {node [circle, draw] {i}}}
                }
                child {node [circle, draw] {c}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {e}}
                    child {node [circle, draw] {d}}
                }
            };
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\centering
\textbf{Tree 5}
\[
\Delta (G) = 3
\]
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 1 \} |$ = 5\\
Number of vertices: $ | \{ v \in V(G) : \deg_G(v) = 3 \} |$ = 3\\
\hfill\\
\quad
(b) Let \( T \) be an arbitrary tree with maximum degree 3. What is the relationship between the number of vertices of degree 1 and the number of vertices of degree 3 in \( T \)? Prove your answer using the handshaking lemma.
\[ \text{[7 marks]} \]\\
\hfill\\
\begin{align*}
\sum_{v \in V(G)} \deg_G(v) &= 2 \left| E(G) \right|
\\
\left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 1 \} \right| + \left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 2 \} \right|&= 2\left| E(G) \right|\\
+ \left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 3 \} \right| \\\\
\left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 1 \} \right| &= 2\left| E(G) \right| - \left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 2 \} \right|\\
 & - \left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 3 \} \right|
\hfill\\
\end{align*}

(c) Generalise the result for an arbitrary tree, by proving a formula for the number of vertices of degree 1 in terms \( n_3 \), where \( n_3 \) is the number of vertices with degree three (for \( d = 3,4,5,...\)).
\[ \text{[7 marks]} \]
\hfill\\
\begin{align*}
\left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 1 \} \right| &= 2\left| E(G) \right| - \sum_{v \in V(G)} \deg_G(v) -\left| \{ \text{deg}_G(v) : \text{deg}_G(v) = 1 \} \right|\\
\hfill\\
\end{align*}

(d) A saturated hydrocarbon (also called alkane or paraffin) is a molecule formed from carbon and hydrogen atoms by adding bonds between atoms such that each carbon atom is in four bonds, each hydrogen atom is in one bond, and no sequence of bonds forms a cycle or network. What is the relationship between the number of carbon and hydrogen atoms?
\[ \text{[3 marks]} \]

\begin{align*}
    H &= 2C + 2
\end{align*}

\textbf{2.} For what values of $n$ does there exist a 5-regular graph with $n$ vertices? Prove your answer.\\
\[\text{[20 marks]}\]\\
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1.5cm} }
\begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
& $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$  \\ \hline
$1$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$2$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$3$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$4$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$5$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$6$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}\\
This is the base case, the complete graph, $K_6$. To be a 5-regular graph we must meet these 3 conditions:\\
\begin{enumerate}
    \item We must have 5 connections for each row and each column
    \item For each entry, $i \times j$ = $j \times i$
    \item There can be no connection for the $i=j$ entry. This causes a line of symmetry.
\end{enumerate}These conditions will only occur when the graph has an even number of vertices. Take the $7 \times 7$ graph below:
\vspace{1cm}\\
\begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
& $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$  \\ \hline
$1$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$2$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$3$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$4$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$5$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$6$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$  \\ \hline
$7$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}\\
We can satisfy condition 3 easily enough however it is not possible to satisfy conditions 1 and 2 simultaneously
\hfill\\
\begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
& $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$2$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$3$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$4$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$5$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$6$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$7$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
$8$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\vspace{1cm}\\
Since n cannot connect to itself we must have at least n=6 vertices. And since all $deg(v)=5$ the Handshaking Lemma becomes:\\
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{v \in V(G)} \deg_G(v) &= 2 \left| E(G) \right|\\
    n*5 &= 2\left| E(G) \right|\\
\end{align*}
And so:
\begin{align*}
    5 \mid \left| E(G) \right| & & 2 \mid n
\end{align*}
Where $n \geq 6$\\
Therefore:
\begin{align*}
    n &= 2k +4\\
    \left| E(G) \right| &= 5k + 10
\end{align*}
\vspace{1cm}\\
\textbf{3. (a)} Prove that for $k \geq 2$, for every tree $T$ with $k$ vertices, every graph $G$ with minimum degree at least $k - 1$ contains a subgraph isomorphic to $T$.\\
\[\text{[15 marks]}\]\\
Every graph, $G$, with $deg_{G}(v) \geq k-1$ will contain as a minimum a complete subgraph, $K_k \subseteq G$, with $k$ vertices. This is because every complete graph with $k$ vertices has $deg_{K_k}(v)=k-1$. The proof is below:\\
\begin{align*}
    K_k \text{ has } \binom{k}{2} \text{ edges}\\
    \text{By the handshaking lemma}\\
    \sum_{v \in V(G)} deg_{K_k}(v) &= 2 \left| E(G) \right|\\
    k*deg_{K_k}(v) &= 2\left| \frac{k!}{2!(k-2)!} \right|\\
    deg_{K_k}(v) &= \frac{(k-1)!}{(k-2)!}\\
    &= k-1
\end{align*}
For every tree, $T$, with $k$ vertices, there will exist a complete graph, $K_k \subseteq G$, with a subgraph that is isomorphic to $T$, that is $S_k \cong T$.\\
Seeing as the complete graph includes all connections between vertices we simply only need to delete the edges that are not found in $T$\\
This satisfies the conditions for a subgraph\\
\begin{align*}
    V(S_k)=V(K_k)\\
    E(S_k)\subseteq E(K_k)
\end{align*}
\\
Now as long as $|V(S_k)| = |V(T)|$ and $|E(S_k)| = |E(T)|$ and there is a bijection \[ \phi: V(S_k) \mapsto V(T) \]\\ such that $\forall$  $u,v \in V(S_k)$ $uv \in E(S_k)$ iff $\phi(u)\phi(v) \in E(T)$\\
\hfill\\
We have an isomorphism\\
\hfill\\
\textbf{(b)} Show that "$k - 1$" in part (a) is best possible for every $k \geq 2$.
\[\text{[5 marks]}\]

\textbf{4.} Apply the algorithm presented in lectures for finding an Eulerian circuit to the following multi-graph. Make choices so that at least three maximal trails are determined. Show all steps of the algorithm.
\[\text{[5 marks]}\]\\
First we check that every vertex has an even degree and positive degree\\
\begin{align*}
deg_G(1) &= 2 & deg_G(2) &= 6  & deg_G(3) &= 4\\
deg_G(4) &= 2 & deg_G(5) &= 6  & deg_G(6) &= 4\\
deg_G(7) &= 4 & deg_G(8) &= 6  & deg_G(9) &= 4\\
\end{align*}
Next we go through the algorithm\\
\hfill\\
C=(1)\\
choose $w=1$\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=-1.5]{1}
    \Vertex[x=2.25,y=0]{2}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=1.5]{3}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=3]{4}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=2.625]{5}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=1.875]{6}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=-1.875]{7}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=-2.625]{8}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{9}
    \Edge[](1)(2)
    \Edge[](1)(9)
    \Edge[](2)(3)
    \Edge[](2)(5)
    \Edge[](2)(6)
    \Edge[](2)(7)
    \Edge[](2)(8)
    \Edge[](3)(5)
    \Edge[](3)(7)
    \Edge[](3)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(9)
    \Edge[](5)(8)
    \Edge[](5)(9)
    \Edge[](6)(7)
    \Edge[](7)(8)
    \Edge[](8)(9)
    \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[bend right]
    \Edge[label=$b$](5)(6)
    \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[bend left]
    \Edge[label=$a$](5)(6)
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\hfill\\
M$=(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9)$ in G - E(C)\\
C=$(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9)$\\
Choose $w=2$\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=-1.5]{1}
    \Vertex[x=2.25,y=0]{2}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=1.5]{3}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=3]{4}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=2.625]{5}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=1.875]{6}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=-1.875]{7}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=-2.625]{8}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{9}
    \Edge[](2)(5)
    \Edge[](2)(6)
    \Edge[](2)(7)
    \Edge[](2)(8)
    \Edge[](3)(7)
    \Edge[](3)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(9)
    \Edge[](5)(8)
    \Edge[](5)(9)
    \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[bend left]
    \Edge[label=$a$](5)(6)
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\hfill\\
M$=(2,5,6)$ in G - E(C)\\
C=$(1,2,5,6,3,5,6,7,8,9)$\\
Choose $w=3$\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=-1.5]{1}
    \Vertex[x=2.25,y=0]{2}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=1.5]{3}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=3]{4}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=2.625]{5}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=1.875]{6}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=-1.875]{7}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=-2.625]{8}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{9}
    \Edge[](2)(7)
    \Edge[](2)(8)
    \Edge[](3)(7)
    \Edge[](3)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(8)
    \Edge[](4)(9)
    \Edge[](5)(8)
    \Edge[](5)(9)
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\hfill\\
M$=(3,7,2,8,5,9,4,8)$ in G - E(C)\\
C=$(1,2,5,6,3,7,2,8,5,9,4,8,5,6,7,8,9)$\\
\hfill\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=-1.5]{1}
    \Vertex[x=2.25,y=0]{2}
    \Vertex[x=1.5,y=1.5]{3}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=3]{4}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=2.625]{5}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=1.875]{6}
    \Vertex[x=-3,y=-1.875]{7}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5,y=-2.625]{8}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{9}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
%\hfill\\

\end{document}

2. Suggestions
Replace your \vspaces by \bigskip or other layout settings. This is very Wordish and usually not needed with Latex.
To avoid clashes from non-cooperative packages I suggest you create your drawings separately AND include them as .pdf using package graphicx.  This gives you much more control and flexibility. See two examples here how it works:

PI controller
including a value chain flowchart

3. Overleaf related?
To check that out I suggest contacting overleaf support. Probably it's not, i.e. it's more likely introduced by your code.

Thank you so much for that, I think it was a conflict between \usepackage{tkz-graph} and \usetikzlibrary{graphs}

@GbBlues It was a conflict between tikz-network and tkz-graph.
